# cd -1, -2, -3 etc in Z shell

Tags: shell, autocomplete, zsh, zsh-completion

How do you set up the Z shell such that typing cd -  gives you a list of previously visited paths, and cd -1, -2, -3, etc. will then take you to the directories?

Comment: Shouldn't this be on either Unix and Linux or Super User?

Answer (score 65):

If you have `setopt AUTO_PUSHD` in your `.zshrc` then `cd` will automatically do a `pushd` of each directory you change to. Taking the example from ZyX:

```
$ setopt AUTO_PUSHD
$ mkdir -p 1/2/3/4
$ cd 1
$ cd 2
$ cd 3
$ cd 4
```

You can see a list of the directories using `dirs`:

```
$ dirs -v
0    ~/1/2/3/4
1    ~/1/2/3
2    ~/1/2
3    ~/1
4    ~
```

To be able to tab complete the list you can use the `+` and `-` arguments with `cd` (`<TAB>` meaning you hit the tab key):

```
$ cd +<TAB>
1 -- ~/1/2/3
2 -- ~/1/2
3 -- ~/1
4 -- ~
```

Or the reverse:

```
$ cd -<TAB>
0 -- ~
1 -- ~/1
2 -- ~/1/2
3 -- ~/1/2/3
```

Then just select the number to go to that directory:

```
$ cd +2
$ pwd
~/1/2
```

### Tab Complete Directories

I always forget the magic sequence to do the following so I updated the answer to explain this part.

The `+` and `-` will only take you to the directory, you can't tab complete the path in the stack (i.e. `cd -2/<TAB>` gives you nothing). To make this work, you can use a tilde (`~`).

Make some directories in `3` to make this example better.

```
$ mkdir 3/foo 3/bar 3/baz
```

Then find the directory in the stack.

```
$ cd ~+<TAB>
1 -- ~/1/2/3/4
2 -- ~/1/2/3
3 -- ~/1
4 -- ~
```

Then use tab completion on an entry.

```
$ cd ~+2/<TAB>
4/    bar/  baz/  foo/
```

Comment: note that it appears you can use this with any command! for example `vi ~+4/it.txt' would edit the file `~/1/it.txt'

Answer (score 7):

If you use `pushd` instead of `cd`, then you can list directories with `dirs` and cd to old directory with `popd`. You can also set `autopush` option to get `cd` behave much like `pushd -q`. Here is an example:

```
setopt pushdsilent # Omit printing directory stack
setopt autopush    # Make cd push directories onto stack
setopt pushdminus  # Invert meanings of +N and -N arguments to pushd
mkdir -p 1/2/3/4
cd 1
cd 2
cd 3
cd 4
popd     # Go to previous directory (3) and remove it from directory stack
pushd -  # Go to previous directory (4)
pushd -2 # Go 2 directories back the directory stack (2)
```

Note that `pushd` does not remove anything from the directory stack, it only rotates it. See `man zshbuiltins` for more details.

Answer (score 0):

c- minus is designed for this kind of requirement.

It support regex match, using md5 hash to void duplication in `pushd`.

Easily to dump and load.

This gif shows some basic operations.

[image: cminus usage]

you can check it out on https://github.com/whitebob/cminus