# zsh tab completion of directory stack not working

Tags: shell, terminal, zsh, zshrc

In [cd -1, -2, -3 etc in Z shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986760/cd-1-2-3-etc-in-z-shell) it appears you can do `cd -<tab>` and `cd +<tab>` to do tab-completion of the directory stack. I think it's supposed to work out of the box on zsh?

However this doesn't work for me. I've even tried the suggestions in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/157773 and that doesn't work either.

I'm using `zsh 5.2 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)` on archlinux.

The output of `setopt` is

```
alwaystoend
autocd
autopushd
cdablevars
extendedhistory
histignorealldups
nohup
interactive
interactivecomments
monitor
nonomatch
promptsubst
pushdminus
shinstdin
zle
```

How can I make tab completion of the directory stack work?

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but did you remember to initialise the zsh completion subsystem with `autoload -U compinit && compinit`?

Answer (score 0):

So, I didn't realize this was a feature but when I tried it in a new tab, it didn't work for me either. But then, after I `cd`'d around a bit, the tab completion worked as expected. Maybe that's your only issue?

Also, as an alternative method, if you're not using the [`z` plugin](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/tree/master/plugins/z), you should check it out. It keeps a global history of all the directories you `cd` into so that in the future you only have to type a small part of the directory name to get back to it.